# File uploading not working MEAN stack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, multipartform-data, mean-stack

I'm beginner in MEAN development and trying to implement CRUD application using it. Initially I've successfully completed my CRUD app using MEAN. Now I'm trying to upload file using angular.js. I got to know that Angular.js doesn't support file upload functionality so by using https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vLHgpOG1cW4 and https://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs
I'm trying to implement this feature.

But somehow the code is not working and giving some angular.js error on firebug console.

`Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/unpr?p0=multipartFormProvider%20%3C-%20multipartForm%20%3C-%20AppCtrl....so on`

Following is my code:

**app/public/controller.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'multipartForm', function ($scope, $http, multipartForm) {
        console.log("Hello World from controller");


        $scope.contact = {};

        var refresh = function () {
            $http.get('/contactlist').success(function (response) {
                console.log("I got the data that I requested");
                $scope.contactlist = response; // This will put data into our html file
                $scope.contact = "";
            });
        };

        refresh();

        $scope.addContact = function () {
            console.log($scope.contact);
            var uploadUrl = '/upload';            
            multipartForm.post('/contactlist', uploadUrl, $scope.contact).success(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                refresh();
            });
        };

        $scope.remove = function (id) {
            console.log(id);
            $http.delete('/contactlist/' + id).success(function (response) {
                refresh();
            });
        };

        $scope.edit = function (id) {
            console.log(id);
            $http.get('/contactlist/' + id).success(function (response) {
                $scope.contact = response;
            });
        };

        $scope.update = function () {
            console.log($scope.contact._id);
            //$scope.contact means sending all form data to server
            $http.put('/contactlist/' + $scope.contact._id, $scope.contact).success(function (response) {
                refresh();
            });
        };

        $scope.deselect = function () {
            $scope.contact = "";
        };

    }]);
```

**app/public/index.html**

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <title>Contact List App</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>


        <div class="container" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading"><h4 class="panel-title">Details</h4></div>
                <div class="panel-body">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name" ng-model="contact.name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email" ng-model="contact.email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Contact">Contact</label>
                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Contact" ng-model="contact.number">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="country">Country</label>
                        <select class="form-control" ng-model="contact.country">
                            <option value="">Select</option>
                            <option value="India">India</option>
                            <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
                            <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
                            <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
                            <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
                            <option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option>
                            <option value="USA">USA</option>
                            <option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
                            <option value="South Africa">South Africa</option>
                            <option value="England">England</option>
                            <option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option>                                
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="gender">Gender</label>
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label>
                                <input type="radio" name="gender" id="optionsRadios1" value="Male" ng-model="contact.gender">
                                Male
                            </label>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <label>
                                <input type="radio" name="gender" id="optionsRadios2" value="Female" ng-model="contact.gender">
                                Female
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="education">Education</label>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="education" ng-model="contact.education.MCA">
                                MCA
                            </label>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="education" ng-model="contact.education.BE">
                                BE
                            </label>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="education" ng-model="contact.education.ME">
                                ME
                            </label>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="education" ng-model="contact.education.BCA">
                                BCA
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Avatar</label>
                        <input type="file" file-model="contact.file">                        
                    </div>

                    <div class="well well-lg text-center bg-gray">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addContact()">Add Contact</button>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="update()">Update</button>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="deselect()">Clear</button>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <h4>Listing</h4>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="contact.names" placeholder="Instant result search">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Number</th>
                        <th>Country</th>
                        <th>Gender</th>
                        <th>Education</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="contact in contactlist| filter:contact.names|orderBy:-1">
                        <td>{{contact.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{contact.email}}</td>
                        <td>{{contact.number}}</td>
                        <td>{{contact.country}}</td>
                        <td>{{contact.gender}}</td>
                        <td>
                            {{contact.education}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="remove(contact._id)">Remove</button>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="edit(contact._id)">Edit</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>



            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script src="controllers/controller.js"></script>
            <script src="services/multipartForm.js"></script>
            <script src="directives/fileModel.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

**app/public/services/multipartForm.js**

```
myApp.service('multipartForm', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.post = function (uploadUrl, data) {

        var fd = new FormData();

        for (var key in data)
            fd.append(key, data[key]);

        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.indentity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        });

    };
}]);
```

**And finally on Node/Express Side: app/server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express(); // using this we can use commands, function of express in this (server.js) file
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs('contactlist', ['contactlist']); // Means which mongodb database & collection we are going to use
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');

// To test whether server is running correctly
/* app.get("/", function(req, res){
 res.send("Hello world from server.js");
 }); */

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public")); // express.static means we are telling the server to look for static file i.e. html,css,js etc.
app.use(multer({dest: './uploads/'}).single('photo'));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // To parse the body that we received from input


//This tells the server to listen for the get request for created contactlist throughout
app.get('/contactlist', function (req, res) {

    console.log("I received a GET request");

     //Creating an array of above data
     var contactlist = [person1, person2, person3];
     // its going to respond to the GET request by sending back contactlist data in JSON format which controller can use
     res.json(contactlist);


    db.contactlist.find(function (err, docs) {
        console.log(docs);
        res.json(docs);
    });

});

// listens for the POST request from the controller
app.post('/contactlist', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    db.contactlist.insert(req.body, function (err, doc) {
        res.json(doc);
    });
});

app.delete('/contactlist/:id', function (req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id; // to get the value of id from url
    console.log(id);
    db.contactlist.remove({_id: mongojs.ObjectId(id)}, function (err, doc) {
        res.json(doc);
    });
});

app.get('/contactlist/:id', function (req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    console.log(id);
    db.contactlist.findOne({_id: mongojs.ObjectId(id)}, function (err, doc) {
        res.json(doc);
    });
});

app.put('/contactlist/:id', function (req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    console.log(req.body.name);
    db.contactlist.findAndModify({
        query: {_id: mongojs.ObjectId(id)},
        update: {$set: {
                name: req.body.name,
                email: req.body.email,
                number: req.body.number,
                country: req.body.country,
                gender: req.body.gender,
                education: req.body.education
            }}, new : true}, function (err, doc) {
        res.json(doc);
    });
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log("Server running on port 3000");
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: It's hard to tell because the service that seems to be at issue is `multipartForm.js`, but you re-copied index.html where it should be. And I assume it's just a typo in your post, but you have the `index.html` looking for a script in `controllers/controller.js`, but you listed your controller.js at the top as `app/public/controller.js`.

Comment: @BennettAdams: Sorry.. silly mistake. I've modified post. please check

Comment: Sorry, nothing's really jumping out at me, other than you're supplying three parameters to the post function when it's expecting two (should be .post('/contactlist' + uploadUrl, $scope.contact)...). Can you elaborate on the error you're getting?